# How to get a value from a void method using Mockito - Groovy / java

Tags: java, groovy, mockito, bdd, powermock

Need some help with this question.

I have a Void method like this

```
    public void doSomething(String a, String b){
    ServiceUtils utils = new ServiceUtils(persistService, randomService)

    String c; 
    String d; 
    c = utils.someMethod(a, b); 
    d = service.anotherMethod(b, null);
    if(utils.validateSomething(d)){
    //...
    }



    persistService.persistMethod(c , d);

    }
```

I need to take the value inside C to move on with my groovy test.

Can't mock utils, its important to the validation. 
Can't mock/( spy(?)) persistService because is used in the utils constructor.

How could I do that using mockito?

Answer (score 3):

The problem is the 'new' in your method:

```
ServiceUtils utils = new ServiceUtils(persistService, randomService)
```

Try to refactor your code: if you inject the 'ServiceUtils' class in the constructor, you will be able to mock this in the test.

Comment: Cant. It's not worth to refactor this method just for this case.

Comment: @MatheusCiaramella If you can't mock anything, why do you want to use a mocking framework to solve this problem?

Comment: I think it is always worth to refactor if you cannot test it!

Answer (score 0):

You could use BDDMockito.verify() and ArgumentCaptor for that, like this:

```
ArgumentCaptor<String> capture = ArgumentCaptor.forClass(String.class);
BDDMockito.verify(persistService).persistMethod(captor.capture(), any());
```

And get the value with:

`captor.getValue()`

This assumes that persistService is mocked with Mockito.

Comment: Doesnt work. persistService in this case should be a Spy method, because is used for fill other things in the whole test... and i cant use spy on this.

Comment: It's an integration test? You would need to show more as it comes to test and the test setup.

Comment: Edited. Sorry for the lack of information. Fixed now.